# Sonar Analysis failed, WARN: Too many duplication references on file

Tags: sonarqube, devops, sonarqube-scan

I am facing a issue while running sonar analysis on node js application, here is the log

```
WARN: Too many duplication references on file coverage/lcov-report/src/api/models/Locations.js.html for block at line 59. Keep only the first 100 references.
WARN: Too many duplication references on file coverage/lcov-report/src/api/models/Locations.js.html for block at line 59. Keep only the first 100 references.
INFO: CPD calculation finished
INFO: Analysis report generated in 462ms, dir size=22 MB
INFO: Analysis report compressed in 14750ms, zip size=4 MB
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: Total time: 1:41.522s
INFO: Final Memory: 21M/80M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: Error during SonarScanner execution
ERROR: Failed to upload report - An error has occurred. Please contact your administrator
```

Comment: That is warning not the error. Could you please share the whole logs of sonarscanner execution.

Comment: here is the logs, https://github.com/myselfme0194/sonarLogs/blob/master/sonarLogs